# uninitialized constant Blog::PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error when I run my Rails app, "uninitialized constant Blog::PostsController"

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :authors
  root to: 'blog/posts#index'

  namespace :author do
    resources :posts
  end

  scope module: 'blog' do
    get 'about'     => 'pages#about',   as: :about
    get 'contact'   => 'pages#contact', as: :contact
    get 'posts'     => 'posts#index',   as: :posts   
    get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show',    as: :post
  end

end
```

posts.controller.rb

```
module Blog
  class PostsController < BlogController   

    def index
      @post = Post.most_recent
    end

    def show
      @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

  private

    def set_post

    end

  end    
end
```

The directory path is as follows:

```
app/controller/blog/posts.controller.rb
```

Comment: Why `PostsController` is inherited in `BlogController`?

Comment: My guess your file naming convention is wrong. File name should be `app/controller/blog/posts_controller.rb` instead of `app/controller/blog/posts.controller.rb`

Comment: Araratan -  just the way it's designed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in Naming convention. 
Here is example of naming convention:

```
Controller Naming Convention

Class: PostsController

File: /app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
```

For more detail on naming convention please check: http://www.ganeshkunwar.com.np/2018/01/02/naming-convention-rails/

Also inherit posts controller from application_controller not from blog controller.

Comment: #SahidurRahmanSuman and #Ganesh that was it.  I changed the period to an underline per your recommendation.